# What is a fault clause in the CLR exception system?

Tags: .net, exception, clr

I was reading [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419661.aspx) on handling corrupted state exceptions and I came across something that puzzled me.

**What is a fault clause?**

See quote from article below:

> An error condition can only pass from
>   the function containing the unexpected
>   condition to that function's caller.
>   Exceptions have the power to pass the
>   results of a function's execution out
>   of the current function's scope to
>   every frame up the stack until it
>   reaches the frame that knows how to
>   handle the unexpected condition. The
>   CLR's exception system (called a
>   two-pass exception system) delivers
>   the exception to every predecessor on
>   the thread's call stack, beginning
>   with the caller and proceeding until
>   some function says it will handle the
>   exception (this is known as the first
>   pass).
>
> The exception system will then unwind
>   the state of each frame on the call
>   stack between where the exception is
>   raised and where it will be handled
>   (known as the second pass). As the
>   stack unwinds, the CLR will run both
>   finally clauses and **fault clauses** in
>   each frame as it is unwound. Then, the
>   catch clause in the handling frame is
>   executed.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [this article](http://dotnet.org.za/armand/archive/2005/11/09/48087.aspx):

> Another example of a SEH clause not available in the C# language is the fault clause. It is similar to the finally clause except that it's only invoked when an exception has been thrown in the guarded block.

[Another article](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/archive/2004/09/15/introduction-to-msil-part-5-exception-handling.aspx) confirms:

> The fault exception handler is similar to the finally block except that it is invoked only if it’s associated try block is left as a result of an exception. After the fault handler has been given an opportunity to execute, the exception continues on its way in search or a handler that is willing to catch it.

Answer (score 2):

The `fault` clause is a clause that is part of the CLI but not available in C#.  It is very similar to a `finally` clause except it is only invoked when an exception was thrown in the `try` block (whereas a `finally` block executes regardless of whether or not an exception was thrown).